# matching API with data services in WSo2

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager

I have created a data service in WSo2 for exposing a table. I have also created an API for this, Now I wanted to match the API with this data service.

Please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the API in the ESB? You can create the API in the DSS itself[1] while creating the data service[1][2]. If you want to expose the datasservice via an ESB then the service endpoint of the created dataservice is available in the dataservice dashboard page which can be directly accessed by the ESB.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Defining+Service+Operations
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Exposing+Data+as+REST+Resources